# Applying the binomial theorem with an arbitrary exponent

Tags: combinatorics, assumptions

I was asked a question by a student today. The solution I came up with seemed a bit suspicious, so I tried to verify it using Mathematica and failed. I created a PDF of my solution which can be found [here](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AgLBTEqWhOJgn1IHge_93VzMjx0l). The problem:

*Consider $\left(ax+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)^n$, where $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Generalize an expression for the constant term with respect to $x$.*

Analytically, I know that if $c$ is the constant term then

$$c=\begin{cases}{n\choose nk/(k+1)}a^{nk/(k+1)}& \text{if $k+1$ divides $n$}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

but cannot get Mathematica to confirm this generally. I've been playing with `Refine` with no progress. I guess I'm asking can Mathematica apply the binomial theorem for a general $n$, giving the answer in $\Sigma$ notation? Then I can use `Coefficient[f[n,k],x,0]` to get a general expression for the constant term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you are looking for here exactly; your PDF proof is convincing, and the result can be checked up to arbitrarily large $n$ depending on how much time and computing power you have (notice that you left out of this question the limitation on the value of $k$ that you have in your original problem, i.e. $1 \le k \le 9$).

For instance, the following empirically checks your result for $n$ up to $20$ and for all admissible $k$ values; the last check returns `True` everywhere:

```
Table[
  {n, k, Sum[Binomial[n, i] (a x)^(n - i) (1/x^k)^i, {i, 0, n}]},
  {n, 20}, {k, 9}
  ];
DeleteCases[Flatten[Coefficient[%, x, 0], 1], {_, _, 0}];
Binomial[#1, #2 #1/(#2 + 1)] a^(#2 #1/(#2 + 1)) == #3 & @@@ %
```

Otherwise, I am not convinced that you can get *Mathematica* to draw such a non-trivial conclusion for you automatically, unless you nudge it forth in the right direction at every step of the way.

As an aside, you asked whether *Mathematica* can apply the binomial theorem for a general $n$, giving the answer in Σ notation. It turns out that *Mathematica* will not "unpack" a binomial by applying the binomial theorem, but it is nevertheless aware of it, as it will do the exact opposite:

```
Sum[Binomial[n, i] (a x)^(n - i) (1/x^k)^i, {i, 0, n}]

(* Out: (a x + x^-k)^n *)
```

Comment: I am sure of the solution from the PDF. I was just seeing if Mathematica could also produce it. Based on what you said, it seems it can't without perhaps some more advanced techniques.